# " It happened that she was out when we called." ('called' here means what?)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> It happened that she was out when we **called**.

'called' means visited or phoned?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British usage up to the middle of the 20th century, this unambiguously meant "came to visit".

In American usage and more recent British usage, it generally means "telephoned".

Comment: Using “called”, especially “called on”, to mean “visited” isn’t that unusual in some areas of the US, particularly the South.

Comment: In Britain, up to maybe World War 2, upper- and upper-middle class people used to leave calling or [visiting cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visiting_card) around which there were elaborate rules of etiquette.